# How to integrate prerender.io into react app

Tags: reactjs, prerender, pre-rendering

I'm currently developing a React app in which the implementation of meta descriptions and OG meta tags is crucial. I'm working on blog pages where the content is dynamically generated from the database based on the URL's slug parameter. I'm using react-helmet to handle dynamic meta tags, but I've encountered an issue where I can't share the URL with other websites to ensure that the OG tags appear correctly.

I've researched the documentation for prerender.io, but I couldn't find a guide for implementing it with React.

I attempted to implement dynamic meta tags for blog pages in my React app using react-helmet. I expected that by doing so, the meta descriptions and OG (Open Graph) meta tags would be correctly set for each blog post, making it shareable on other websites and social media platforms. However, I encountered a limitation where sharing the URL with other websites didn't display the OG tags correctly, leading to issues when sharing blog posts.

My react app is hosted on different domain and have a node backend server hosted on different domain.